# Open facebook iOS app on a specific page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does someone know how to deep-link into Facebook iOS app?

I googled it and found solutions like:

fb://PAGENAME

fb://page/PAGENAME

fb://profile/PAGENAME

http://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME

...but none of them are working anymore, neither on Facebook iOS 6 app, nor on Facebook iOS 7 app.

The only solution I found is to link to: http://m.facebook.com/PAGENAME.
This works by opening Safari, but the experience is pretty bad as the user is not necessarily logged in.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with the page id:

```
fb://profile/137947732957611
```

Comment: @pbaris +100 for you.

Comment: Side note: this URL won't open on the Simulator because there's no Facebook app. Test `UIApplication canOpenURL:` first and fall back to the universal `http://www.facebook.com/<page_id>`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that using the page id with a simple Facebook url, like in the example below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: http://www.facebook.com/PAGEID]];
```

it will …

1. If Facebook is installed: open the page in the app
2. Else: open the page in Safari

I tested this on iOS 7, can't guarantee it works on older versions.

Comment: This will open app after loading page in safari, try fb://profile/xxxx instead